# How to make array responsive to the browser window height to visualize audio

Tags: javascript, arrays, visualization

I'm visualizing audio using the Web Audio API in JavaScript. I'm trying to normalize the array of audio data so that the visualization is responsive to the browser's inner height. However, I'm facing an issue where the maximum value in the array always corresponds to the maximum height, regardless of the actual audio data.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```js
draw(bufferLength, barWidth, dataArray, padding) {
  for (let i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
    const max = Math.max(...dataArray);
    const normalizedArray = Array.from(dataArray, value => value / max);
//maximum height is 60% of screen heigth
    this.barHeight = normalizedArray[i] * (window.innerHeight * 0.6);
    // Rest of the code for visualization
    // ...
  }
}
```

which approach you suggest?